# TypeCasting Map <int, class A> to <int, class B> in C++

Tags: c++, oop, casting, maps

So I have a function that accepts a map as an argument as follows.

```
function do_dope_stuff(int arg1, std::map<uint32_t, parent_class>& my_object){
    //do some programmer magic
}
```

This function is then called from a couple different places where one of the map ID's is of a dervired object type.

```
do_dope_stuff(int, std::map<uint32_t, child_class1>&) 

or

do_dope_stuff(int, std::map<uint32_t, child_class2>&)
```

Well this obviously doesn't work because there is no matching function call since the maps are of different types. So my essential question is how I can typecast the map to make this work without having to create a copy of this huge map and explicitly convert the individual objects to a compatible type. Because the child_class object can be promoted to the parent class but the compiler doesn't like me trying to use C style casting on the map. I also don't want to change the function prototype or overload this since its used in a huge testbench.

Comment: _"how I can typecast the map"_ - You don't, use a function template if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

THe problem with your design is that your map contains values.  As objects of the derived class might contain more data than objects of the parent class, even if some casting would be possible (which it is not), there would be [slicing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing).

**Approach with polymorphism**

Another approach could be to design your class in a polymorpphic way, and store in your map not the object value, but a smart pointer to an object:

```
std::map<uint32_t, shared_ptr<parent_class>> my_map;
my_map[777]=make_shared<parent_class>(); 
my_map[911]=make_shared<child_class>(); // you can mix ! 
my_map[89]=make_shared<parent_class>(); 
do_dope_stuff(1, my_map);
```

For this to work as expected, you need to use virtual functions for every function where the child has a different behaviour than the parent:

```
struct parent_class {
    virtual void say_hello() { cout << "Hello, I'm parent"<<endl; }
    virtual ~parent_class() {}
};
struct child_class : parent_class {
    void say_hello() override { cout << "Hello, I'm child"<<endl; }
};
```

Your `do_dope_function()` could then enjoy polymorphism and process a `std::map<uint32_t, shared_ptr<parent_class>>`, whether the elements in the maps contains pointers to the parent class, to the child class, or a mix of both.

**Approach with polymorphism and templates**

Of course, this doesn't solve the case where you have a `std::map<uint32_t, shared_ptr<child_class>>`.  But do you really need such a specific map, when your design now allows for a more flexible polymorphic container ?

If yes, you could extend the solution by defining your function as a template.  Example:

```
template <typename T>
void do_dope_stuff(int arg1, std::map<uint32_t, shared_ptr<T>>& my_object){
    //do some programmer magic
    for (auto &x:my_object) {
        cout << x.first<<": ";
        x.second->say_hello();
    }
}
```

Here a **[live demo](http://ideone.com/EBUklE)** wrapping up the different cases.

**Template only, if you want to stick to your original design**

But perhaps you want to stick to your initial design, keeping values in the map, and avoiding polymorphism.

Then you could just define your function as a template. But you need to know at compile time the type of objects in the map that has to be processed, and all the objects in the map would then have to be of the same type.  This would look like:

```
template <typename T>
void do_dope_stuff(int arg1, std::map<uint32_t, T>& my_object) {
    //do some programmer magic 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Not too sure if this is what you're looking for, or it will work but:
You can

1. Use templates in the function definition
2. have a map to object pointers rather than objects, and copy the pointers which is cheaper than copying objects
3. pass a pointer to the map (or maybe a void pointer) and recast that in the function

Answer (score 1):

Use pointers or references to the base (parent class), for example:

```
void do_dope_stuff(int arg1, std::map<uint32_t, parent_class&>& my_object){
    //do some programmer magic
}

void do_dope_stuff(int, std::map<uint32_t, parent_class&>&) {...}


void do_dope_stuff(int, std::map<uint32_t, parent_class&>&) {...}
```

Or if you want static polymorphism, then use templates, for example:

```
template<typename T>
void do_dope_stuff(int arg1, T& my_object){
        //do some programmer magic
}

template<typename T>
void do_dope_stuff(int, T&) {...}

template<typename T>
void do_dope_stuff(int, T&) {...}
```